Why does the following run into an infinite recursion error?
I have the following code:
def aoeu():
    r = lambda: 5
    s = r
    r = lambda: s() * 6
    s = r
    r = lambda: s() // 2
    print(r())

When run, it errors with:
  File "/Users/nyap/tasks/spreadsheet/spreadsheet/aoeu.py", line 10, in <lambda>
    r = lambda: s() * 6
                ^^^
  [Previous line repeated 993 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

The same thing happens when using s = copy.deepcopy(r) and even:
    def s():
        return r()

and:
    def s(r):
        return r()

Why? And is there a way to fix it so it doesn't happen without introducing another variable since there's a loop in the actual code?
This is with python-3.12.6

"so it doesn't happen without introducing another variable since there's a loop in the actual code?" why does that matter?

@juanpa.arrivillaga, consider the second and third settings of r to be in the loop such that there may be more settings of r. The issue, as pointed out in some answers below, IIUC, is that id(r) becomes constant which leads to the recursion. Using different variables would mitigate that but that's not possible, at least when done naively, in a loop. Passing r into a lambda gets around that problem

Ah, I think I understand now, yes, passing in the function as an argument to a function factory is the best way to go (regardless, IMO), but another approach would be to use a container for the functions you are creating in a loop. But that's not as clean

Good question. It has to do with mutability within python closures, which is sticky. tl;dr: the closure within r gets mutated by line 5, causing s to point to itself.
Longer version:
The address of s within the closure created on line 4 gets changed by s's assignment on line 5: unintuitive. It means that s points to itself by line 7, illustrated in this sketch pointer diagram (nested boxes represent closures):

The diagram demonstrates that the address pointed to by s is the same one holding s within its own closure: s effectively points to itself.
Here's a full program state map, with flagrant use of shorthand: The format is--
name@number meaning variable state at a given line;
address (from a run of pdb on VSCode);
body (what's in the cell there);
[maybe] 'will loop', means calling the function at this address will cause divergence.

The fact that python's default variable assignment mutates the internals of closures is a common source of difficult-to-find bugs. Examples like these help catch them before they can occur.
The following fixes the issue:
def aoeu():
    r = lambda: 5
    r = (lambda s: lambda: s() * 6)(r)
    r = (lambda s: lambda: s() // 2)(r)
    print(r())

The Y Combinator Explained in Python goes more in-depth about this technique

I'm just going to point out, using lambda expressions like this goes against PEP8 style guidelines.

When r is called in the print statement, it will call s. s is the same as the previous definition of r, which calls s again causing the recursion. This can be confirmed by looking at the memory addresses of these functions.


The problem is that the references to the lambdas are overridden and they get lost.
Here's what I mean, line by line:

First, you declared r = lambda: 5. This will make r point to a memory address like 0x10 (just an example).

Then, you make s = r. Here, s points to 0x10 too.

Now, you said that r = lambda: s() * 6. Let's say that this function was created in the memory address 0x20 (so r points to 0x20). You might think that the s() call here will be a call to the 0x10 address that we talked above, but that's not exactly what happens. The interpreter will check where the s function starts in its symbol table. It will start executing in the most recent value assigned to s. At this time in execution, the value of s would be in fact 0x10.

Here you said that s = r again. Now you are updating the s value to the address of the new r() function you created above. Therefore, s = 0x20.

At last, you redeclared r again as r = lambda: s() // 2. Let's say this was created in 0x30, so r = 0x30.


Summarizing
The addresses of the functions in the symbol table would be:

r = 0x30
s = 0x20

Executing

When you call print(r()), the interpreter will check where the r function starts and will see that, in this case, r start executing in 0x30.

The code in 0x30 is s() // 2. Notice that we have an s() call here.

The interpreter will then check where s starts, and will see 0x20. And what code we have in 0x20? Is s() * 6!


Now you will see why you got stuck in an infinite recursion. In 0x20 you have a call to s(), right? And s points to 0x20 again! Here's your infinite recursion.
To solve this, you must create different variables to each function as others suggested. Hope this helps!

puting this in terms of memory addresses kind of muddles things, the explanation is not really correct, because functions don't work like functions in a language like C (although, the logic is the same as outlined here)

Because print(r()) is calling lambda s of the previous line, which is still referencing lambda r and then it goes into an infinite loop. Changing the name of the variables will help preventing this problem.
Another example could be:
def aoeu():
    r=aoeu()
    print(r())
aoeu()


Maybe we should make the names of variables (r, s) to be clear.
def aoeu():
    # r = lambda: 5
    # s = r
    # r = lambda: s() * 6
    # s = r
    # r = lambda: s() // 2

    s1 = lambda: 5
    s2 = lambda: s1() * 6
    r = lambda: s2() // 2

    print(r())


I said without introducing new variable names
